# Can I use a shock pump to inflate a tube?

Tags: repair, innertube, pump, inflation, shocks

I know that shock pumps are meant for high pressure applications so that they can withstand high pressures needed by suspension shocks.

However, can I use a shock pump to inflate my tire in a pinch if I run out of CO2?  How would it compare to a standard mini-pump in terms of volume?

Comment: Is it that you're carrying a shock pump while riding?

Comment: You aren't going to hurt anything, and as Benzo mentions you can use an adapter to do presta. Please try and report back how long it takes to get a decent pressure.

Comment: Yeah, it would be an interesting experiment to try.  Probably no worse than some of the cheap compact pumps.

Comment: one can get a dual, shock+tire, pump, for example from Serfas

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Note: this calculation makes many assumptions, so it's only useful in an 'average use case', not some sort of exact measurement. If you find better information, please post it and I'll update the answer.*

How many pumps you would need to fill up a tire depends on many variables. First, the volume of your inner tube, which can be approximated as a torus (doughnut-shape) atop the rim size of a given diameter. You can find yours approximated [on this graph](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mrjoeball/4525757653/).

- 26" Mountain Bike, 2.1" tire width = 4.8L
- 29" Mountain Bike, 2.1" tire width = 5.2L
- 700C Road Bike, 35mm tire width = 2L
- 20" BMX Bike, 1.85" tire width = 3L

I'm finding pump specifications quite difficult to find (I need piston diameter and stroke length), but [here's a comparison](http://www.competitivecyclist.com/review-pumps-co2-inflators/shock-pump-shootout_620.html) of some shock pumps on an empty shock cylinder of a 2007 Fox 36 RLC 160mm Fork.

- Average Accu-Gage Pressure Reading after 100 strokes: 77.2 psi
- My best guess at RC2 air chamber specifications: 1" (25.4mm) diameter, 160mm length (max travel). If someone can find accurate specs or the true volume, I'd appreciate it.
- Fox RC2 Air Volume (estimated): `Vcylinder = pi*r^2*h` = 81 mL

So then, IF pumping air into different volumes is linearly proportional (it's not, but somewhere in the ball park), and you wanted to inflate the tires listed above to ~77.2psi, it'd take about this number of pumps with the 'average' shock pump:

<kbd>Tire Volume</kbd> <kbd>Ratio of Tire to Air Shock</kbd>  <kbd>Number of Pumps to ~77.2 psi</kbd>   
<kbd>26" Mountain Bike, 2.1" tire width</kbd> <kbd>4.8L</kbd>             <kbd>59:1</kbd>                                   <kbd>5,900</kbd>                                          
<kbd>29" Mountain Bike, 2.1" tire width</kbd> <kbd>5.2L</kbd>             <kbd>64:1</kbd>                                   <kbd>6,400</kbd>                                          
<kbd>700C Road Bike, 35mm tire width</kbd> <kbd>2L</kbd>                <kbd>25:1</kbd>                                   <kbd>2,500</kbd>                                          
<kbd>20" BMX Bike, 1.85" tire width</kbd>      <kbd>3L</kbd>                <kbd>37:1</kbd>                                   <kbd>3,700</kbd>

So, perhaps if it was a life or death situation, you have a lot of time on your hands, or you just can't afford that gym membership, *you might **want** to pump a few thousand times to fill your tire*. You probably don't.

By contrast, if you're just looking for this functionality in one device, you could just use a dual purpose model, such as this [Specialized Pump](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/tools/cycling-tools/shock-pumps/product/review-specialized-airtool-shock-frame-pump-11-45346), that can inflate both high pressure, low volume containers (like your shock) and low pressure, high volume containers (like your tire).

[image: Specialized Dual Use Pump]
<sub>(source: [bikeradar.com](http://cdn.mos.bikeradar.com/images/bikes-and-gear/tools/cycling-tools/shock-pumps/1317898932266-au7vptd57qp9-399-75.jpg))</sub>

You twist the handle to select between uses, and save yourself a few thousand pumps.

Comment: Raw data. Awesome!

Comment: Nice answer, but I don't think most people run a mountain bike tire at ~77 psi (maybe on pavement, but they'd likely be using smaller slicks in that case).

Comment: Well, my city mountain bike tires runt at 65 psi. +1 more for "*or you just can't afford that gym membership*"

Comment: I have Kenda hybrid tires on my mountain bike, which are 2.1" wide and take 65 psi. If, however, you're referring to most MTB tires that are between 35 and 40 PSI max, just half it: 2,950 pumps for a 26" tire and 3,200 for a 29" (38.6 PSI)

Comment: I'd also be worried about the pump seals overheating and loosing pressure.  Some pumps get really hot with use - even the old school frame pumps could burn skin during an enthusiastic inflation session!

Comment: The total air volume in a shock is quite a bit larger than the "operating" area - there is a "dead" volume where the air inside is pushed when the shock is at the highest compression. I don't think it more than doubles the internal volume though, so I think your calculations are in the right ballpark

Answer (score 5):

A shock pump is designed to fill a very small volume of space with very high air pressures.

A tire pump is designed to fill a large volume of air, to relatively low pressures, pretty quickly.

You can technically fill a schrader valve tube using a shock pump, but because the volume of air for each repetition of the pump will be so low, it might take a week to fill the tire.

A shock pump will not mate with a presta valve at all.

On a practical level, you should use a shock pump to fill your shocks, and a tire pump to fill your tires.

Comment: Is a week realistic? Maybe 10 mins? I have filled a car tire to 35 psi with a bike floor pump, so I know what it's like to fill a huge tire with a small pump.

Comment: Couldn't you also just use a presta adapter to fill a presta tube?

Comment: @Benzo:  It wasn't intended to be realistic.  It was deliberate exaggeration.  However, it wouldn't be 10 minutes.  It took more than an hour to fill a tire with a shock pump, the one time I was desperate enough to try.

Comment: About an hour... yeah, seems like that's better than useless, but far from useful unless you're really stranded.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, in fact I only owned a shock pump for two years I was in the UK and was using it on my rides and at home. The reason was that I also used it for skike tires which are high-pressure and low-volume and use the Schrader valve. And alas, I did use it many times, my rims were horrible and would cut the valve regularly even after taping the sharpest edges.

Some models of shock pumps feature a knob allowing you to switch between a high-volume (nothing comparable to a floor pump!) and high-pressure. Mine current shock pump BETO MP-036 has this useful feature where I can start pumping at the high-volume mode and switch to the slower high-pressure mode around 50 PSI where it becomes too hard to pump otherwise.

Using the Presta-Schrader adaptor can be anoying. Special care must be taken with valves that can have their inner part unscrewed. It is easy to loosen it when unscrewing the adaptor and you will lose all the pressure immediately and the inner part with the adaptor may be shot away with the burst.